# Tomcat 8.5 starts with OpenSSL Exception

Tags: openssl, tomcat8

I have installed a new tomcat (8.5) on my server and tried to configure https on port 8443. When I start the tomcat server/service I get an error message. I've looked up on google but haven't found anything helpful. So can someone explain me the exception and how do I solve the problem.

Here parts of catalina.out:

> 08-Nov-2018 13:55:21.872 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine. Failed getting cipher list
>    java.lang.Exception: Not implemented
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.newSSL(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.(OpenSSLEngine.java:76)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getImplementedProtocols(OpenSSLUtil.java:61)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.(SSLUtilBase.java:55)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.(OpenSSLUtil.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation.getSSLUtil(OpenSSLImplementation.java:36)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:103)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:86)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

My server.xml configuration:

```
<Connector 
port="8443" 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="200"
scheme="https"
secure="true" 
SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/nKeystore"
keystorePass="****"
sslProtocol="TLS"
clientAuth="false"
/>
```

Additionally tomcat never opens any web-applications or even a test-HTML. I always get the message "

> The requested resource is not available or does not exist

". Is there any relation between this error message and the one before?
Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: I reinstalled the whole tomcat and configured ssl/tls without apr. Then it worked fine